# Partially transparent .png in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use a .png image as background in a window. The image is completely black with a transparent background. The following code in the window constructor works just fine with a .jpg:

```
this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\images\\background.jpg")));
```

But something goes wrong with the transparency when I use the .png file. I've tried playing around with the Opacity and OpacityMask properties, but either a) nothing is shown or b) the window background is completely black.

Thanks in advance for any ideas/solutions!

Comment: The path in your code is a JPG, not a PNG, are you sure you're loading a PNG?

Comment: The problem occurs when loading the PNG. When I load the JPG, there's no problems since the background is white in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Set [`AllowsTransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency) to true in your window.

Comment: That forces me to set WindowStyle to None, which removes borders and possible other things?